# How to show the Virtual Keyboard when text input is focused on Kivy Python

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, raspberry-pi3, touchscreen, virtual-keyboard

I want to show the virtual Keyboard when the text input is focused on the Kivy UI on the 7" touch screen of the Raspberry pi 3b.

Answer (score 1):

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'systemandmulti')
```

Read more in Kivy [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.vkeyboard.html#).